# How to upload an mp3 to Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I know it's possible to upload videos to Facebook. Is it possible to upload an mp3 to Facebook using their user interface?

Comment: In this case I closed the other one as this one has 10x the views and therefore contains the terms that people are actually searching on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to upload an MP3 directly to Facebook. The only thing you can do is to host the mp3 somewhere else and provide the link to it via a status update/comment.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the software you have available, you can create a video that employs an empty (black) background and/or maybe some text and include the mp3 as the audio portion of the video.

Then upload that new video to FB.