# Is it still possible to paste an mp3 link into a Facebook status?

Tags: facebook, audio, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an mp3 to Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25392/how-to-upload-an-mp3-to-facebook)

I work for a public media radio station. We are currently working out a plan for extending our brand through the use of social media. One of the ways we are wanting to do this is by posting listenable audio clips from the programs we produce.

Based on my research, it seems that as early as last year, it was possible to post a player for a specific mp3 by pasting a direct link into the status update box. However, when I attempt to do so, it only posts it as a link, rather than with a player like it apparently has in the past.

Did Facebook remove this feature? Did it have something to do with the Timeline update? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If it doesn't work on more than 1 account, it means Facebook has changed something.

Comment: There were a couple of users using the mp3 upload (not necessarily the status update) feature as an exploit for uploading animated gifs. It could be related so I imagine functionality has been limited.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you want but you might want to consider hosting your mp3 on Soundcloud and posting a link to it. 
Edit: what about uploading it as a video with a static image (i.e. your logo)? Seems like YouTube integration is much more common.

Comment: We looked into it, but the free version is limited in terms of how many people it can reach and how much content it can handle.

Comment: *Edited with additional idea.